# Pytest Captures Logfile Even With Logfile Capture Disabled

Tags: logging, pytest, traceback

Running pytest with `--capture=sys` should capture only stdout/stderr, but if I do `--tb=auto --capture=sys` the traceback still includes debug statements that should only be routed to a log file. I see the same behavior even with `-s`.

I have a lot of debug statements being logged to a file that I do NOT want to see on my console. So I have my `logging.StreamHandler` logger set to `logging.INFO` and a `logging.FileHandler` set to `logging.DEBUG`.

When I run my test, if there is a failure and a traceback is printed, it always prints the `Captured log call` and `Captured stdout call` sections if I use `--tb=auto` and even `--tb=short`. The only way to stop this from happening is by using `--tb=no`, but then I lose valuable traceback info.

Minimal example (I called the file `test_basic.py`):

```py
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fh = logging.FileHandler(filename="log.txt")
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(fh)

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(sh)


def test_one():
    logger = logging.getLogger("test_one")
    logger.info("Logging at INFO level")
    logger.debug("Logging at DEBUG level")
    assert False
```

Output for `python -m pytest --tb=auto --capture=sys`:

```
==================================================== FAILURES ====================================================
____________________________________________________ test_one ____________________________________________________

    def test_one():
        logger = logging.getLogger("test_one")
        logger.info(f"Logging at INFO level")
        logger.debug(f"Logging at DEBUG level")
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_basic.py:19: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ----------------------------------------------
Logging at INFO level
----------------------------------------------- Captured log call ------------------------------------------------
INFO     test_one:test_basic.py:17 Logging at INFO level
DEBUG    test_one:test_basic.py:18 Logging at DEBUG level
============================================ 1 failed in 0.09 seconds ============================================
```

Desired output:

```
==================================================== FAILURES ====================================================
____________________________________________________ test_one ____________________________________________________

    def test_one():
        logger = logging.getLogger("test_one")
        logger.info(f"Logging at INFO level")
        logger.debug(f"Logging at DEBUG level")
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_basic.py:19: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call ----------------------------------------------
Logging at INFO level
============================================ 1 failed in 0.09 seconds ============================================
```

If I use `--tb=no` I get rid of the `Captured log call` section but also all traceback info:

```
============================================== test session starts ===============================================

test_basic.py F                                                                                            [100%]

============================================ 1 failed in 0.07 seconds ============================================
```

How can I achieve my expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `--show-capture=stdout`.

It is a little bit confusing that disabling capture does not do this though. I would have liked `-s` to override `--show-capture=all` (the default).

Comment: Thank you for finding and sharing your own solution with others. You can accept your own answer to close the question. I'll delete this comment once you did. Just give me a ping comment (create a comment with `@socowi accepted` and immediately delete that comment).