# Suppressing INFO messages during testing, from python backoff

Tags: python, logging, pytest

I have a `pytest` test which calls some code set to back off on exceptions and retry, defined like so:

```py
@backoff.on_exception(backoff.constant, AssertionError, max_time=4)
def get_assigned_task(self):
```

When this is run, if it errors (common), it logs a message for every retry, which looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------- Captured log call ----------------------------------------------
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.5s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.0s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.3s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.0s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.0s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))    
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.2s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))    
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.4s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))    
INFO     backoff:_common.py:86 Backing off get_assigned_task(...) for 0.4s (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))    
ERROR    backoff:_common.py:101 Giving up get_assigned_task(...) after 9 tries (AssertionError: assert 0 == 1
 +  where 0 = len([]))
```

I can suppress *all* of that with `--show-capture=stdout` (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792975/pytest-captures-logfile-even-with-logfile-capture-disabled)), but what I actually want is to suppress the INFO blocks and keep the ERROR block. I've also tried setting `logging.basicConfig(level="ERROR")` or doing the same with the config passed to `logging.config.dictConfig`; no dice. There doesn't seem to be any special config for thi in `backoff` or `pytest` either.

How can this be arranged?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Logging Configuration](https://github.com/litl/backoff#logging-configuration%20section%20of%20the%20backoff)  README.

You could set the logging level to `ERROR` rather than the default `INFO`.  Alternatively, you could disable backoff logging altogether with `logger=None`.

Comment: As mentioned, I did try that.